# Set the MangedObjectContext of a UITableViewController with a UINavigation Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I have a problem when I try and set the `managedObjectContext` of a `UITableViewController`. I am using storyboards and this is my code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Segue"]) {
    [[segue destinationViewController] setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
}
}
```

**My destination `UITableViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.**

When I run my code I get the following error:

```
[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First address the navigation controller.

```
UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
UITableViewController *destinationController = 
      (UITableViewController*) navController.rootViewController;
destinationController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Or use your own custom class instead of `UITableViewController`.